# Rewriting and Redirection using mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite

so I have an apache server and I am trying to access an external google doc. My main issue here is capturing the key of a key value pair in a url and then redirecting to that key. I have the regex required that puts the key into it's own group but unfortunately I am a bit green to Redirecting and Rewriting URL's.

It may be worth noting that by default my Apache Server is looking for directory called 'redirect' every time I try to leave the site

I have tried using "%{QUERY_STRING}" as Rewrite Condition and I feel like this is the correct approach because I have tested my my regex and it works according to multiple online regex testers

//This is my URL:

http://example.com/redirect?url=**https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%myForm%2Fd%2Fe%2F1FAaBUNCHOFSTUFFBELONGING TO GOOGLE%2FviewmyForm**

//Regex to capture the value in it's own group:

```
redirect(.*)url?=(.*)
```

//This is my code for the capturing and redirecting:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}" redirect(.*)url?=(.*) 
RewriteRule ^redirect(.*) %2 [R=301]
```

Expected Results: Replace the URL with the key that has been captured using regex

Actual results:

> Error 404 redirect/ not found on this Apache server

Comment: You should show an actual [mcve] formatted correctly so we have more context. Also, show the full error you get from your server.

Comment: @jdv apologies for the lack of context, my head was a bit foggy at the time of writing but I've since solved my issue.